# Seek framework to implement a dashboard

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dashboard

Consider the term 'dashboard' as a generic UI pattern where multiple views stream different aspects of an site - new users, new orders, new questions, and so on. Essentially splitting a stream of log entries, each to its own viewport. Viewports might want to drill down to detail records or might want to hide itself until/unless wakened by some other event.

Working against the IIS7, .net MVC, jQuery stack.

At [Ajax based Dashboard On LargeData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327321/ajax-based-dashboard-on-largedata-asp-net) I see recommended: http://www.dynamicdashboards.net/

which looks interesting. Any alternatives?

thx

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sbarski/dashing.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use MVC and if you take a close look at [this page](http://ksis.sch.sa/Activities/11) you can see that i stream a partial view in whenever i change pages. It's not hard to do this yourself. My humble opinion is that a dashboard framework might be overkill and unnecessary complication. I can get you code samples if you like.

Comment: Still getting my head around Partials ... samples would be greatly appreciated. thx

Comment: I don't know how clear this will be but try- [This is my partial](http://db.tt/gaSRhT7) that i load into the page, and [this is the Detail view](http://db.tt/R1FqjwE) that loads it - line 53 is the ajax that does the loading. [This is the controller that contains the action "DetailPhotoPage"](http://db.tt/DYygFG2) that you will want to look at. Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. There's a lot of noise in those files but hopefully you can follow the basic idea of loading the partial view using ajax. Refer to the original website link to see how it all fits in on the page.

Comment: That page is long since left my control. Sorry about the link.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative open source framework named Dropthings. But capability and support is limited. I'm also looking for an ajax dashboard framework for asp.net and using Oracle. Upto now best seems [Dynamic Dashboards](http://www.dynamicdashboards.net).